# Speed up writing multiple image TIFF?

Tags: c, file-io, tiff

I'm trying to write stacks of images to TIFF files. The images are of size 256*256 pixels, each stack containing 1000 images. Writing one of those files takes about 4 minutes - so there's most likely something wrong with my code.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
void Tiff_WriterSplit(float data[], int PicNum, int WIDTH, int LENGTH, char PATH[]) {
     int i;
     int rows = LENGTH, columns = WIDTH;
     TIFF* tif;

     if (PicNum == 0)
         tif = TIFFOpen(PATH, "w");
     else
         tif = TIFFOpen(PATH, "a");

     TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, columns);
     TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, rows);
     TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
     TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 32);
     TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT, SAMPLEFORMAT_IEEEFP);

     for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
         TIFFWriteScanline(tif, &data[i * columns], i, 0);

     TIFFWriteDirectory(tif);
     TIFFClose(tif);
}
```

This function `Tiff_WriterSplit` will be called for each image of the stack. The first image will have `PicNum = 0` to open the tiff file in `w` mode, all the following images will have a `PicNum > 0` to open it in `a` mode. Writing this starts at about 40 MB/s and gets slower and slower with increasing filesize - down to about 1 MB/s. How can I optimize the performance?

Comment: On what device are you writing?

Comment: I'm running this on a specific "working horse" which takes the data from a server (via 10 Gbit ethernet) and writes it back to the server. I'm also writing the raw data in binary format to the server with ~100 MB/s. So, hardware should not be the issue here...

Comment: @thomas Thanks for the suggestion! It is indeed a problem with the server - storing the files locally takes <1 s per file. I'll try to store them locally and copy them over to the server afterwards to avoid writing those tiny chunks over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing tiffs is a lot easier than reading tiffs.  The overhead of libtiff can be quite limiting for write performance.  Assuming you have a buffer that is in some pixel format that can be represented by a tiff header, the steps to write a tiff,

1. Write tiff header
2. Write image data
3. Write directory (tag table).

For a multi-image tiff, we are limited by 4GB tiff limit of 32bit entries.  However, if your images are always of the same geometry (width, height, planes, depths), the directory entries in the tag table can be written out after writing all of the image data.  You are free to place the directory at the end (or beginning) of the tiff binary.  If at the end and you know the number of images, you can form the directories entries before a write of the image (construct table in place).  If the API doesn't allow you to know the number of images before hand, then the final file offset must be calculated in the IFD after the final image is written.

Directly writing a tiff can allow you to use `fallocate`, `mmap` and other OS features which may speed up writing multi-image tiffs.  The job is a lot more computationally challenging if need to translate the image format as it may involve signal processing.

Single image plane writing can be over 3x faster with a direct write vs libtiff.  If libtiff is constantly recalculating and repositioning the tag table at the end of the tiff (IFD), then this will be O(n^2) per image.

I used this technique to stream scientific image sensor data to disk from a [genicam](/questions/tagged/genicam) device.  It allows capturing at much higher FPS.

The combination of vision analysis to find regions of interest with the multi-tiff (directory) structure would allow multiple regions of interest to be saved for each frame in single tiff.

#### Reference

- http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm
- http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tiff/

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar performance issues. It appears that (as of libTiff version 4.0.9) there is a performance issue in TIFFWriteDirectory that causes its run time to scale with the number of images already present in the multi-page TIFF file.

I don't think that's anything to do with how the TIFF file specification is written - I think it's a performance bug in libTiff.

I find that it takes 21ms to save my first 80 images (of the order of 24,000 bytes), but that this rises linearly to 3 seconds by the time I have written 9,000 images to the same file. 99.5% of the time is spent in TIFFWriteDirectory (calling through to TIFFLinkDirectory, with the majority of that time spent in _tiffReadProc).