# TIFF - libtiff performance issue for long datasets (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, performance, tiff, libtiff

Trying to read and write a large standard tiff with the characteristics below, I have encountered a slow down of performance after each frame is processed:

- 10000 frames
- Frame size 512x512
- 16 bits per sample

It seems that the instruction TIFFWriteDirectory has a linearly progression of execution time.
There is a difference of computation time from the 1st frame compared to the last computed frame of around 400ms. I do not think that there is any reason to have this difference taking into account how libtiff writes IFDs metadata.

I have tried using different versions of libtiff 4.1.0, 4.2.0 and 4.3.0, but the result is the same. In the logs and forums I do not see anything relevant regarding this issue and I was wondering if anyone has encountered the same performance issue with large data-sets.

My program simply reads an input TIFF image (all the IFDs and image data), then some changes are applied to the image data and saving again all IFDs to the output TIFF file along with the image data.

Within a for loop there is the following instructions where TiffWriteDirectory is called:

```
ifd.offset = (TIFFSeekFile(m_tiff,0,SEEK_END)+1) & (~((toff_t)1));
ifd.set_fields(m_tiff);
TIFFDeferStrileArrayWriting(m_tiff);
TIFFWriteCheck(m_tiff, 0, "TiffWrapper (pass 1)");
return TIFFWriteDirectory(m_tiff) != 0;
```

In this thread ->  [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364163/speed-up-writing-multiple-image-tiff)

The user [@jonny-taylor] seems to have the same problem but the discussion did not continue.

Thanks for your help and contribution.

Comment: A brief search finds libtiff's home page. And there's a link to the project's mailing list. It doesn't look very busy, but that's not surprising for a project of this kind. And, the mailing list likely has many long-time subscribers with years of expertise in using this library. That would be the first place I'd look to clarify this kind of an inquiry -- a resource explicitly dedicated to the software library -- instead of a generic web site like Stackoverflow.

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?  Did you turn optimizations on when building the program?  A question concerning C++ performance should always be accompanied by these details.

Comment: This is a known issue. See discussion at https://www.asmail.be/msg0055011809.html

Comment: Sorry, it is my first comment on stackoverflow. Yes, I use clang with -o3 optimization in win10, but this issue is related to libtiff. The project's mailing list is not super busy. As I saw a thread in stackoverflow with a similar performance issue I thought it could be related. Regarding @cgohlke link, my test is with 50k images but they do not propose any solution, I will continue to explore. Thanks for your help. I will send a message to the libtiff mailing list as well.

Comment: The thread on the libtiff mailing list contains a link to a patch. I'm not sure it's possible to fix this issue without changes in the libtiff library.